# Конвертация с mbr в gpt

Tags: windows, windows-10

я использую windows 10, и мне нужно конвертировать системный диск с mbr в gpt как это можно сделать с сохранением всех данных и работоспособностью системы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это могут это сделать:

- AOMEI Partition Assistant
- EaseUS Partition Manager
- MInitool partition wizard

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).